# What middleware offers the easist migration path between AWS/Azure/Openstack and On-premises deployments of enterprise applications?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, integration, enterprise

What middleware (preferably non-commercial) offers the a migration path between AWS/Azure/Openstack and On-premises deployments of large applications - thus increasing agility? It is a difficult problem, but am looking for any new developments in this area. Seems like it should be an active niche given all the new cloud possibilities.

Comment: This type of question doesn't fit here, as it's asking for a product recommendation (plus it's opinion-soliciting).

Comment: Would it be possible to edit this question to make it not so "opinion soliciting". Say if I just ask for preferably opensource middleware that made such a thing possible?
I think I will do that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rightscale](http://rightscale.com/) seems to be the market leader in this. Their pricing certainly emphasizes "enterprise" and "lucrative".

In the DIY world, many libraries try to make a common layer between these. `boto`, for instance, can store data on S3, Google Cloud Storage, and OpenStack's [Swift](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Swift/APIFeatureComparison). Many other services are designed to be API-compatible, such as [Heat](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat/BotoCli) (cloudformation) and [Nova](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Nova/APIFeatureComparison) (EC2).

Comment: This is "an" answer but not "the" answer. Can't really be answered since the question is  1) opinion-based and 2)  asking for a recommended product.

Comment: Well, it certainly helped me. Not sure why it is so terrible to solicit opinions, but I suppose I am a newbie here and don't get the system yet.I will avoid asking such questions in the future.

Comment: This is how StackOverflow is. Questions are closed all the time if they're about product recommendations or opinions on something. And, you marked this answer as an accepted answer, yet it's just one of many possible solutions.

Comment: Heck, so what. Let's have a discussion. Or should we take our clicks and eyeballs elsewhere?